# Count total sumar sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Quiero mostrar el total de registro y a la vez sumar ese total

```
SELECT 
t.empresa, 
COUNT(t.idespecialidad) AS count, 
e.nombre AS nombre_especialidad

    FROM tickets as t

        INNER JOIN especialidad AS e ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad

    WHERE t.empresa = '3' AND t.status= '4' AND t.cierre_ticket between '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'

UNION ALL

    SELECT 'SUM', COUNT(t.idespecialidad), e.nombre AS nombre_especialidad

        FROM tickets as t

            INNER JOIN especialidad AS e ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad

        WHERE t.empresa = '3' AND t.status= '4' AND t.cierre_ticket between '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'

 GROUP BY e.nombre
```

Esto es lo que obtengo:

```
empresa count   nombre_especialidad     
3       9       Mantención Central Telefónica
SUM     1       Aire Acondicionado
SUM     2       Electricidad
SUM     4       Mantención Central Telefónica
SUM     1       Revisión Enlace
SUM     1       Traslado Mobiliario
```

Comment: es tal como dice el mensaje de error, la columna `idespecialidad` es ambigua, porque puede ser de la tabla `tickets` o `especialidad`. Agrega el prefijo tal como lo hiciste en `e.idespecialidad`

Comment: Le agrego el prefijo en ambas consultas?

Comment: Debes usar prefijo antes de cualquier columna que tiene el mismo nombre en más de una tabla dentro de la misma consulta

Comment: Le agregue los sufijos pero me devuelve asi:

Comment: empresa  count  nombre_especialidad  
3  9  Mantención Central Telefónica
SUM  1  Aire Acondicionado
SUM  2  Electricidad
SUM  4  Mantención Central Telefónica
SUM  1  Revisión Enlace
SUM  1  Traslado Mobiliario

Comment: FIjate lo que subi

Comment: No está claro cuál es el problema... ¿La consulta devuelve algo que no es lo que esperas? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál el obtenido?

Comment: Mira tengo N especialidad quiero sacar un reporte general de todas las especialidades con un cout y a su vez sumar el total que me arroje el cout. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Fijate que me esta duplicando "3       9       Mantención Central Telefónica" quiero que no me muestre el nombre de la especialidad en el campo que me trae el total

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que es esto lo que buscas:

```
SELECT  t.empresa, 
        COUNT(t.idespecialidad) AS count, 
        e.nombre                AS nombre_especialidad
        FROM tickets as t
        INNER JOIN especialidad AS e 
            ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
        WHERE   t.empresa = '3' 
            AND t.status= '4' 
            AND t.cierre_ticket between '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
        GROUP BY t.empresa, e.nombre    

UNION ALL

SELECT  'SUM', 
        COUNT(t.idespecialidad), 
        NULL
        FROM tickets as t
        INNER JOIN especialidad AS e 
            ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
        WHERE   t.empresa = '3' 
                AND t.status= '4' 
                AND t.cierre_ticket between '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
        ORDER BY 1
```

#### Comentarios:

- La primer consulta es por la que obtienes la cantidad de `idespecialidad` por `t.empresa` y `e.nombre`. Nota que hay que indicar a ambos en el `GROUP BY`, MySql es permisivo en esto, pero te recomiendo como buena práctica siempre indicar todas las columnas que muestras en el `SELECT` que no tengan función de agregación.
- La segunda consulta, es básicamente la primera pero sin ningún `GROUP BY`, por lo que el `COUNT` contará todas las filas.
- Revisa el `ORDER BY`,  si quieres el total como última fila, debes asegurarte que `'SUM`' sea alfabéticamente posterior a cualquier `t.empresa`